# Registering keystrokes in the CLI on Mac immediately

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I want to programm a little CLI app with nodejs.

I want a certain String to get logged, depending on what arrow key was stroked. I tried the keystroke library which as some flaws.
![enter image description here][1]

First of all, I need to push 'Enter' before it registers the keystroke.
Also the CLI shows random characters when a arrow key is pressed.

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (ch, key) {
  if (key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  } else {
    console.log('test!');
  }
});
```

Output

```
^[[A
test!
^[[B
test!
^[[C
test!
```

Any idea how to do that better?

Comment: Please post text, not images :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a better alternative, working out of the box:

```
var stdin = process.stdin;
stdin.setRawMode(true);
stdin.resume();
stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

stdin.on('data', function(key){
    if (key == '\u001B\u005B\u0041') {
        process.stdout.write('up'); 
    }
    if (key == '\u001B\u005B\u0043') {
        process.stdout.write('right'); 
    }
    if (key == '\u001B\u005B\u0042') {
        process.stdout.write('down'); 
    }
    if (key == '\u001B\u005B\u0044') {
        process.stdout.write('left'); 
    }

    if (key == '\u0003') { process.exit(); }    // ctrl-c
});
```